# How to Open (.sps,.csv and .sav) with SPSS as default application?

Tags: default, appmenu, mime-type

I installed SPSS24 (a statistics application) on my laptop because i need it for work.

I created a SPSS.desktop file and now i can find ich with the Dash search. So far so good.

But now i want that the files which are ending with .sps, .csv, .sav are automatically openend with SPSS when i double click them. I tried "right click", "properties" and then choose a default application but SPSS is not in the application list and i cant find a way to insert a command.

How can i assign it properly?

Edit: i was able to assign .csv files to SPSS because i could find a proper MIME-Type. But for .sav and .sps there i cant find them?!

Comment: how did you install spss? through wine? have you tried the opensource clone pspp (in the repos)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the right entry for .sav is application/x-spss-sav=blabla.desktop

Simply add it to ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list

so....closed

Comment: Had the same issue, and tried this but it didn't work. I also added 'MimeType=application/x-spss-sav' to the desktop entry.